# Is is possible to send form data to an external link with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

For example, consider this code:

```
<form method = post action="URL">
    <Input type = text name= first name />
    <Input type = text name= last name/>
    <Input type = submit value= submit name=submit/>
<form/>
```

In the code above we can see form data in headers. Can the same functionality be replicated in Angular?

To be clear, I want to pass input values to an external link via the `post` method in Angular.

Comment: do you want user to be navigated somewhere with a post request, or you want to make an AJAX call from your app and continue using it after submit?

Comment: Passing the input values to external link via post method in angular

Comment: Make call in my form and sending/ submitting the values to external link

Comment: I mean, should user stay on your page, or be fully redirected to other website after that?

Comment: Fully redirect to other website along with the values

Comment: Can we submit a form automatically in angular 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rakesh, if you only want to send a value -typical to an API that update a dbs- it's only using httpClient, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

```
constructor(private:httpClient:HttpClient){}

submit()
{
    this.httpClient.post('your-url',
           {firstname:'yourName',lastname:'lastname'})
}
```

if you need to show a page that not belong to the app -typical external url to login or a virtual tpv-, you can create a form "outside Angular" adding ngNoForm to your form

```
<form method ="post" action="URL" ngNoForm >
</form>
```

Of course you can use variables